# Error estimation of convergent series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, approximation

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{14}{n^2+n}$$
Determine how big n has to be such that the error is less than 0.001.

I tried approximating the error using $|S-S_n^*|$, where
$S\approx S_{n}^{*}= S_n +\frac{A_{n+1}+A_n}{2}, A_n=\int_n^{\infty}f(x)dx$ so that it satisfies $|S-S_n^*|\le\frac{A_n-A_{n+1}}{2}$.
I got that $n\ge 13999.0002$ which means that $n$ has to be $14000$.. This doesn't seem to be correct, did I misunderstand the approximation method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac {14}{n^2 + n} = \frac {14}{n(n + 1)} = \frac {14}{n} - \frac {14}{(n + 1)}$

$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {14}{n^2 + n} = 14$

But that doesn't seem to be your question.

$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {14}{n^2 + n}=\sum_\limits{n=1}^{N-1} \frac {14}{n^2 + n} + \sum_\limits{n=N}^{\infty}\frac {14}{n^2 + n}$

and how big does N need to be for:

$\sum_\limits{n=N}^{\infty}\frac {14}{n^2 + n} < 0.001$

$N = \frac {14}{0.001} = 14,000$

But, if you want to estimate that using the integral
$\int_N^{\infty} \frac {14}{x^2+x} dx$

$14 \ln (\frac {N}{N+1}) < 0.001$

And you still get $N\approx 14,000$

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying!
Yes, I used partial fractions to find the integral, and got $n=14,000$. The program I am using, however, doesn't seem to agree..